# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' in pyannote speaker diarization package

Tags: database, speaker, diarization

When working with the pyannote python package from GitHub (tutorial link -> https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio/blob/develop/tutorials/voice_activity_detection.ipynb)

I receive the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpPrf.png)

The preprocessors were working a week ago, but now it errors out over a lack of items found.. can anyone give insight?